# how to divide an integer number in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am dividing a metric which is integer. I'm using union with another table where this Apps in as Int64 data type. That's why I have used cast here to convert integer. But I'm not getting the correct value. When I use Float64 instead of integer then it gives me the correct value. Please suggest what to do?

```
 cast(CASE WHEN Channel = "Search"  THEN Apps/2  ELSE Apps END as int64)  as Apps
```

Comment: when you are converting into int64, that would truncate any number, so it's better that you cast the int64 column in the other table into float

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting the float64 into an int64 which would lead to a data loss, cast the integer column in the other table to float64